# AJAX data array drill down

Tags: jquery, ajax

Once upon a time, I was using PHP to display all my data.  Now I want to use AJAX.

Where I used to get my data in PHP:

```
<?php 
    $array = $this->disparray;

    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        $mlsnum = $value['1'];
        echo "<div>" . $mlsnum . "</div>";
    }
?>
```

Where `$this->disparry` was some function in joomla that put data into an array.  The structure of which looked like

```
array (

    0 => array (
        0 => data1,
        1 => data2,
    );,

    1 => array (
        0 => data1,
        1 => data2,
    );,

);
```

now I have an AJAX function that works (or at least returns an `alert`.

```
var results = $('#hidden').serialize();

var url = 'index.php?option=com_mls&view=list&format=raw&' + results;

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function(data){
        $('#test').html(data);
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('There was an error loading your request.  <br />Please try again later.');
    }
});
```

Nothing is written to `#test` and nothing is displayed in the alert(even though the alert happens).  Why for?  I should be getting a whole lot of array data, except I don't even get a lump of coal.

Comment: If you manually navigate to the page it's calling do you get expected results?

Comment: You're right, navigating to the page doesn't display/return anything.  Would AJAX display a `success:` if that were the case?

Comment: Try setting the `dataType` to text (or whatever data type you're trying to retrieve). `$.ajax({url: url, dataType: 'text'`

Comment: Changed it from `return` to `echo` and I got "Array" back.

Comment: That works.  what about other formats? Will `contentType: JSON` be enough to get the data into JSON format, or will I need a PHP function to translate during the retrieval?

Comment: `contentType: 'JSON'` will only let it parse JSON - javascript has no idea what is going on inside the server, php data structures, etc. I don't work with PHP but [I believe](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) there's a built in JSON encoder

Comment: Yes, there is an encoder in PHP, but I didn't know if `contentType` would be enough or I would have to make PHP encode it for me.  also, sweet user name.

Comment: PHP has to encode the JSON itself, setting `contentType` merely lets the JSON be decoded by jQuery.

Comment: Wanna put that in an answer and get street cred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're encoding your php array before echoing it out so jQuery can parse it.

Answer (score -1):

can you declare the url variable inside the ajax call? looks like it is not in the ajax function's scope

this should work, if you need to declare outside, give a try without var

```
   $.ajax({
      url:'function to call url',
...
...

});
```

Comment: -1, they're in the same scope and if it wasn't declared it would give an error about `url` being `undefined`.

Comment: `ajax` defaults to `'GET'`